# Table accordion using php and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I'm trying to make an accordion table for data obtained from database. 
Just want to show description data in row below after clicking on row.I have been trying by modifying lots of code I found.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/XE6AG/2/ (thats what i want)
or the code shown below.

I mostly get raw description data above the actual table.

```
<body>
    <?php
    include("info.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM list1 ORDER BY `FName` ASC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    ?>
    <table class="research">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>

        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):?>

        <tr class="accordion">
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['FName'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo "<a href='http://".$row['URL']."'>".$row['URL']."</a>"?>

            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['Age'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['Address'];?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php echo $row['Description'];?>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </table>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".research tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
        $(".research tr:first-child").show();
        $(".research tr.accordion").click(function () {
            $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: so what is the problem with what you posted? you didn't tell us what's working or not.

Comment: I'm trying to make a table accordion like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XE6AG/2/ but with data from mysql datbase. If I edit the scirpt - add the php, mysql stuff like shown, its not working. All the rows in table are printed (nothing is hidden), but I want the description row to be hidden until I click on the row above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to "solve" it  using bootstrap

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />
    <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com" />
    <title>The web</title>
    <style>
        .hiddenRow {
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        tr.accordion {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

            tr.accordion.active, tr.accordion:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }

            tr.accordion:after {
                content: '\002B';
                color: #777;
                font-weight: bold;
                float: right;
                margin-left: 5px;
            }

            tr.accordion.active:after {
                content: "\2212";
            }

        tr.panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            background-color: white;
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</head>
    <body>
    <?php
    include("info.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM list1 ORDER BY `FName` ASC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
    <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
        <?php $i=0; while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $i++; ?>
        
        <tbody id="accordion" class="accordion-group">
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#name_<?php echo $i;?>" class="accordion-toggle accordion">
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['FName'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "<a href='http://".$row['URL']."'>".$row['URL']."</a>"?>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['Age'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['Address'];?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="panel">
                <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="name_<?php echo $i;?>">
                        <?php echo $row['Description'];?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            <?php }?>
       
    </table>
    <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var tr = this.nextElementSibling;
   if (tr.style.maxHeight){
     tr.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
     tr.style.maxHeight = tr.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
  }
}
    </script>
</body>
```